# How to extract particular part of <li> tag and omit <span> tag inside of that <li> tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I just need to extract the dollar amount from `li` tag. So the output should be like `$63,606.40 - $70,137.60`

```
html = 
<li>
Regular - Full time  
<span>-</span>
$63,606.40 - $70,137.60 Annually 
</li>

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
r = requests.get('https://www.governmentjobs.com/careers/home/index?agency=sdcounty&sort=PositionTitle&isDescendingSort=false&_=', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
job_elem  = soup.find('li', attrs = {'class':'list-item'}) # gives container with all we need
salary = job_elem.findAll('li')
print(salary[1])
```

**output:**

```
<li>
Regular - Full time                                                            <span>-</span>
                            $63,606.40 - $70,137.60 Annually                        </li>
```

Comment: get it as text - `salary[1].get_text(strip=True)` - and then you can find first `$` to get beginning, and third space after first `$` to get end.

Comment: if it has always the same text then you could slice it. `text = salary[1].get_text(strip=True)` and `print(text[20:-9])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has always the same text then you can get it as string

```
    text = salary[1].get_text(strip=True)
```

and slice it

```
    print(text[20:-9])
```

---

Working code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

r = requests.get('https://www.governmentjobs.com/careers/home/index?agency=sdcounty&sort=PositionTitle&isDescendingSort=false&_=', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

all_jobs  = soup.find_all('li', attrs = {'class':'list-item'})

for job in all_jobs:
    salary = job.find_all('li')
    text = salary[1].get_text(strip=True)
    print(text[20:-9])
```

Result

```
$63,606.40 - $70,137.60
$125,000.00 - $135,000.00
$140,000.00 - $150,000.00
$79,144.00 - $96,200.00
$64,355.20 - $79,040.00
$50,356.80 - $61,193.60
$225,000.00 - $250,000.00
$87,000.00 - $100,000.00
$115,000.00 - $124,000.00
$84,864.00 - $104,228.80
```

---

**EDIT:** If text can be different then you can use `$` to find beginning of salary and third space after first `$` to find end of salary.

```
text = '$' + text.split('$', 1)[1]
text = ' '.join(text.split(' ')[:3])
print(text)
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

r = requests.get('https://www.governmentjobs.com/careers/home/index?agency=sdcounty&sort=PositionTitle&isDescendingSort=false&_=', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
all_jobs  = soup.find_all('li', attrs = {'class':'list-item'}) # gives container with all we need

for job in all_jobs:
    salary = job.find_all('li')
    text = salary[1].get_text(strip=True)
    text = '$' + text.split('$', 1)[1]
    text = ' '.join(text.split(' ')[:3])
    print(text)
```

---

**BTW:** You could also use `regex` to search it in text. But I skip this part.

---

**EDIT:** I made version with regex

```
import re

text = salary[1].get_text(strip=True)
text = re.findall('\$[0-9,.]+ - \$[0-9,.]+', text)
print(text[0])
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

r = requests.get('https://www.governmentjobs.com/careers/home/index?agency=sdcounty&sort=PositionTitle&isDescendingSort=false&_=', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
all_jobs  = soup.find_all('li', attrs = {'class':'list-item'}) # gives container with all we need

for job in all_jobs:
    salary = job.find_all('li')
    text = salary[1].get_text(strip=True)
    text = re.findall('\$[0-9,.]+ - \$[0-9,.]+', text)
    print(text[0])
```

Comment: I added version with regex